# jQuery .click .appendTo not loading other javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It's kind of hard to explain what is happening so I will do the best I can. I have a simple jQuery script that when you select the "add" button it adds another row of input boxes so if a user wanted to continue to add dates they could or just accept and move on. That part works ok as seen below on my fiddle.  However, when the user clicks on "add" it will add a select drop-down and a input box, those input boxes also had js from pickadate.js to select their date. Whenever you select the "add" option to add more rows it seems like it's not loading any of the js as the input box is completely blank and not holding either the class itself nor the js it's suppose to. Also it is not saving correctly on my server-side it's like it's ignoring it on both sides. Here is a image of what it's showing on Firebug https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncxwG.png

**jsfiddle script:**

http://jsfiddle.net/q3jrU/

**full js code:**

```
        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
    monthsFull: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
     disable: [
        1
    ],
     min: new Date("today"),
     today: '',
     clear: ''
    });

    var i = $('input').size() + 1;

    $('#add').click(function() {
        $('<div><select name="office" id="office"><option value="test">Select Office </option></select> {{ Form::text('date[]', Input::old('date[]'), array('class' => 'datepicker', 'placeholder' => 'Select a date')) }}</div>').fadeIn('medium').appendTo('.inputs');
        i++;
    });

    $('#remove').click(function() {
    if(i > 1) {
        $('.datepicker:last').remove();
        i--;
    }
    });
});     
    </script>
```

fyi the script is at the bottom of the page itself. The server side is laravel 4. How can I get my js to read correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `.pickadate()`, you're telling it to add that plugin to all existing matched elements (in this case, any existing element with the class `datepicker`). But when you called `.pickadate()`, those dynamically added fields didn't exist.

So after you create them, you need to call `.pickadate()` on them as well. I would do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var pickadateOptions = {
        monthsFull: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
        disable: [
            1
        ],
        min: new Date("today"),
        today: '',
        clear: ''
    };

    // get all existing elements with the 'datepicker' class and apply the plugin
    $('.datepicker').pickadate(pickadateOptions);

    var i = $('input').size() + 1;

    $('#add').click(function() {
        $('<div><select name="office" id="office"><option value="test">Select Office </option></select> {{ Form::text('date[]', Input::old('date[]'), array('class' => 'datepicker', 'placeholder' => 'Select a date')) }}</div>')
            .fadeIn('medium')
            .appendTo('.inputs')
            .find('input')
                .pickadate(pickadateOptions); // apply the plugin to the new element
        i++;
    });

    $('#remove').click(function() {
        if(i > 1) {
            $('.datepicker:last').remove();
            i--;
        }
    });
});
```

Also, each of the newly created `<select>` boxes will have the same name and ID, which is invalid. The text input looks fine, though.

Comment: that's a start. The calendar will now show! However, it does show in the input after selecting the date. It acts like nothing was done.

Comment: @Lynx: I just edited my answer. I think the problem was that the way I had it written, we were applying the datepicker to the div, not to the input. So before calling `.pickadate()`, first do a `.find('input')` to apply the datepicker to the input instead of the div.

Comment: I saw it the second you edited it! That will work thanks! You're a master of your craft!

Comment: I figure I might ask you rather than posting another question. How can I apply the remove to each new row so that if I wanted to delete individual rows I could instead of the last row? I attempted this;     $('#remove').click(function() {
        if(i > 2) {
            $(this).parents('.newrow').remove();
            i--;
        }
    }); but that didn't get me anywhere also added it to the click div with a class of newrow. If you perfer I could ask a question and link it to you for some rep

Comment: You're the bomb. haven't tried on my development but that should work! Thanks a lot :)